# Is the letter u silent in draught?

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letters

I know that this word is pronounced as /dra:ft/ but do we consider the u to be silent?
I have heard of 2 rules for silent u

1-when u comes after g

2-when u comes before a vowel

but none of them apply to this word, can someone clarify it for me?

Comment: One more question produced by the myth that there are pronunciation rules embedded in English spelling, if one only knew enough to find them. Once more pointing out that **All letters are silent**. Real language makes noise; writing doesn't, and English spelling does not represent English pronunciation; spelling and pronunciation have to be learned separately, because you can't predict one from the other well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *u* is not really silent, it's part of the *au* digraph although in this particular word that digraph has a slightly odd pronunciation. The *gh* is not silent either, as it's that which produces the /‍f/ sound.

*Draught* is simply pronounced the way it is. The word *cough* is similar, in that *ou* is pronounced /‍ɒ/ as though it were just *o* and the *gh* is /‍f/.

The similar-looking words *fraught, aught, caught, haughty* are more "regular" in that *au* is pronounced /‍ɔ:/ and the *gh* really is silent: /‍frɔ:t/, /‍ɔ:t/, /‍kɔ:t/, /‍hɔ:tɪ/.

English is tough /‍tʌf/, especially where words originating in Old English and Middle English are concerned. They are now so irregular that they just have to be learned.

Comment: It’s tough, and thank you for the clear answer!

Comment: In the United States, _draught_ is pronounced the same as _draft_; it's considered a variant spelling like _theater_ and _theatre_ or _labor_ and _labour_.

Comment: Not to mention *drought* having the vowel of *cow* yet *wrought* having the vowel of *caught*.